# PostgreSQL ODBC Driver for IBM i Compile Error

Tags: postgresql, odbc, ibm-server

I am attempting to compile the PostgreSQL ODBC driver on our IBM i system, and I'm getting a strange error. The version I'm trying to compile is 12.02, since that's the version of PostgreSQL we have installed.

The command I'm running:

```
./configure --with-libpq=/QOpenSys/pkgs/lib/postgresql12/lib --with-iodbc=/usr/local/iODBC
```

This is where it stops:

```
checking for PQsetSingleRowMode in -lpq... no
configure: error: libpq library version >= 9.2 is required
```

I can confirm that libpq.so and libpq.so.5 are both in that directory, and the version of PostgreSQL is 12 so it should be >= 9.2. I have uninstalled and re-installed via yum all of postgresql, just to get the same message.

The relevant error in config.log is

```
configure:12757: gcc -o conftest -g -O2 -Wall  -I/usr/local/iODBC/include -I/QOpenSys/pkgs/lib/postgresql12/lib//include -I/QOpenSys/pkgs/lib/postgresql12/lib//include/postgresql/internal -I/QOpenSys/pkgs/lib/postgresql12/include -I/QOpenSys/pkgs/lib/postgresql12/include/internal  -L/usr/local/iODBC/lib -L/QOpenSys/pkgs/lib/postgresql12/lib//lib -L/QOpenSys/pkgs/lib/postgresql12/lib conftest.c -lpq  -lpthreads -liodbcinst  >&5
ld: 0706-006 Cannot find or open library file: -l pq
        ld:open(): No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 255 exit status
```

I do not know what that means, and searches have come up with nothing useful.

What do I need to change to get this to work? Alternatively, is there a repo that has a pre-compiled PostgreSQL ODBC driver for IBM i that I could pull from, that I just couldn't find?

Comment: If this question is a better fit for the DBA stack, let me know.

Comment: Does the file `libpq.so` exist in `/QOpenSys/pkgs/lib/postgresql12/lib`? In that actually directory, not in some subdirectory? Is the lib correct for your architecture?

Comment: Yes it exists in that exact location, and the lib was installed via yum directly from an IBM repo that they recommended, so I can only assume that it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

can you try

```
--with-libpq=/QOpenSys/pkgs/lib/postgresql12 (without the /lib)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).